# How to execute a block (identified by pointer) from lldb

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, lldb

I'm in the lldb debugger within the iOS simulator and I have the address for a block. I want to try to execute it. I tried the first thing that came to mind (see below) but it didn't work. Is there a way to do this?

```
(lldb) po 0x2c7140
(int) $2 = 2912576 <__NSGlobalBlock__: 0x2c7140>
(lldb) po 0x2c7140(NO, @"Test")
error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer
```

I also tried **call** but apparently that is not a command in llvm? It was available in gdb.

```
(lldb) call (void)0x2c7140(NO, @"Test")
error: 'call' is not a valid command.
```

I realize just now that the first attempt would have failed anyhow since po isn't going to work with a void return value, but the question still stands...

Answer (score 11):

You need to cast your number to a block pointer.

```
expr ((void (^)(BOOL,NSString*))0x2c7140)(NO, @"Test")
       |        |    |          |        |
  Return type  Argument types  Address  Call
```

(`expr` is lldb's replacement for `call`)

I have not actually tested that this works, but have confirmed that lldb recognizes the cast. You may need to split it into two `expr` commands, one to do the cast and one to do the call:

```
expr (void (^)(BOOL,NSString*))0x2c7140
expr $n(NO, @"Test")
```

where `$n` is the identifier given to the result of the first expression, which will be a part of lldb's output. I believe you can simply use `$` to mean "the previous result", but have not tested this.

Comment: I'm unable to fully test this right now. Trying it gives me: error: blocks support disabled - compile with -fblocks or pick a deployment target that supports them. IT seems like a step forward though. I will keep shaving the yak.

Comment: That's why I didn't test it too. I assumed it was because I was trying to attach to a running process, but maybe this version of lldb just doesn't support executing blocks.