# Call a block from XCode's debugger

Tags: xcode, debugging, objective-c-blocks

Can I call a block from the XCode debugger? I just tried:

```
po zoomCurve(0)
```

Which has the type:

```
typedef CGFloat (^STAnimationCurveBlock)(CGFloat t);
```

And the debugger says:

> error: called object type 'STAnimationCurveBlock' (aka '__block_literal_generic *') is not a function or function pointer
>   error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: If you use lldb, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304090/how-to-execute-a-block-identified-by-pointer-from-lldb

Comment: Is lldb the default debugger, or, how can I tell which I'm using?

Comment: Ah – anyway, casting the block pointer worked for me. That's an annoying to need to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10307517/2547229), the debugger doesn't seem to know the type of the block. You need to cast the block to its type. In the specific case you have there:

```
po ((CGFloat(^)(CGFloat))zoomCurve)(0.9)
```

For some reason, casting to the `typdef` type also doesn't work, and gives the same error. Specifically, this will give the same error:

```
po ((STAnimationCurveBlock)zoomCurve)(0.9)
```